The Darkening of the Sky During a Total Solar Eclipse
During a solar eclipse, the sky maintains a high brightness even when the Sun is, say, 95% eclipsed by the Moon. During the last ten seconds before totality is when most of the darkening of the sky occurs.
How can you predict the apparent brightness of the sky as the Moon eclipses the Sun?  You may assume there are no clouds in the area.
Related Question:
Change of visible area as one circle covers another?

The actual well known observation you report suggests to me that the problem may require physics, not just the mathematics that tells you the rate at which the covered portion of the sun varies.

Is this a homework question?

No, it is not a homework question.

Nevermind, I found the answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/262813/why-does-the-sun-have-to-be-nearly-fully-covered-to-notice-any-darkening-in-an-e?rq=1

An important point is that our perception of brightness is approximately logarithmic, so each halving of the light is perceptually the same.  The sky is not totally dark at totality, so you might model the apparent brightness as $\log (x+a)$ where $x$ is the fraction of the solar disk exposed and $a$ is the brightness at totality.  $a$ will be much smaller than $1$, so the step from no coverage to half coverage will be the same as the step from half to quarter, and probably for another few steps before $a$ starts to matter.  Now you have to find a function of time that gives the fraction of the solar disk that is covered.

This comes across as a guess. It doesn't discuss how one would go about VERIFYING this hypothesis, nor does it cite anyone who has used this hypothesis with data? This has basically statistical implications as well, so perhaps it doesn't belong on this site.
